# open lightning action in subtab

Tags: lightning-experience, service-cloud-console, action

I'm actually using the service console, and I saw that if I set my account as the main tab, I can open an account, and each related record that i open , will open as subtabs. This is very good, fine.

Now I have an action, when i execute the action which will create a new record, it open the new record as a Main tab and not subtab of the account, even if the record created is related to the main, which is my account.

How can I specify my standard action to open the record as subtab and not a main tab ?

If i'm using a lightning component, as action, I may have more flexibility, but I'm not able to use the subtab() method as the method takes a URL as parameter, and in lightning, we don't use URL but methods to navigate to component. How can I achieve this?